# Why setting Button.Background in Trigger is not working?

Tags: xaml, triggers

The following MultiTrigger works fine but if I try to Change Button.Background to Red, its not working. Any thoughts?

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions >
                        <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>            
        </Style>       
    </Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of Button's ControlTemplate. If I change my OS theme to Windows XP from Luna this works fine. Take a look at these links

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b23e8641-977f-4127-a96a-d329a1ba04e4/

http://www.wiredprairie.us/journal/2006/09/wpf_decorators_build_your_own.html

Answer (score 0):

Properties are set by a [Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx), meaning some properties will overwrite your `Style` properties.

So check if you have set a `Background` directly on your `Button`, because this will overwrite your `Style` background setter; you might want to consider using the Style for your default background as well, like so:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions >
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
         </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>            
</Style>
```

Comment: I dont have inline background property. Other properties like `FontWeight` work fine, only problem is `Background`. I wonder it has something to do with system theme/style